# Downloaded git, what about security of installation?

Tags: git, security, download

Downloaded Git-2.28.0-64-bit**.exe**.
I am used to check some hashsum of a download prior to installation.
As I understood, this would lower the risk of faked URLs and some man-in-the-middle attacks.

But I cannot find a SHA512 or the like value of the .exe. *Can I simply trust the git download*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was [requested before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56687640/6309) (for Github to provide a sha256 checksum alongside their release assets), but this is not yet available.

Some projects are adding an additional asset representing the checksum, as in [`coreybutler/nvm-windows` releases tag 1.1.7](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/tag/1.1.7)

[Git for Windows releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) adds a SHA-256 table for all its release:

```
Git-2.28.0-32-bit.exe   9b83b16f1d73212492f21d9bffe41c4b5ce8393a356af96bf8271652c04dfe8f
```

So you can control the integrity of your downloaded artifact that way.

And, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55601369/6309), those exe are signed as well, which means you can use [SignTools.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) to check that signature.