# Ansible get_url Download file only if changed

Tags: ansible

I want to download the files from the yaml file download.yaml only if they changed.

I already found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22668463/10966928 but it seems ansible still downloads the whole file, even when it is not changed

task from playbook.yaml:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Download File
    get_url:
      url="{{ item.value.url }}"
      dest="{{ item.value.dest }}{{item.value.file }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', dl) }}"
```

download.yaml:

```yaml
dl:
  4mlinux:
    dest: /var/www/html/live/asset-mirror/releases/download/36.1-39ff9a19/
    file: vmlinuz
    url: https://github.com/netbootxyz/asset-mirror/releases/download/36.1-39ff9a19/vmlinuz
  4mlinux-antivirus:
    dest: /var/www/html/live/asset-mirror/releases/download/37.0-0.103.2-ba9e3ece/
    file: vmlinuz
    url: https://github.com/netbootxyz/asset-mirror/releases/download/37.0-0.103.2-ba9e3ece/vmlinuz
  4mlinux-bakandimg:
    dest: /var/www/html/live/asset-mirror/releases/download/36.0-262576bf/
    file: vmlinuz
    url: https://github.com/netbootxyz/asset-mirror/releases/download/36.0-262576bf/vmlinuz
```

Edit:
To make my question more clear.
Github does not provide hashes for releases see here [Where to get MD5 hashes from a GitHub release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671303/where-to-get-md5-hashes-from-a-github-release)

I want to avoid the calculation of the checksum myself, because the `download.yaml` gets generated from another yaml file.

It would be sufficient if the `get_url` module only checked the size of the file.

Edit2:
Ansible still downloads the whole File.
Here is an example Verbose Ouput:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={'key': 'regolith-current', 'value': {'dest': '/var/www/html/live/ubuntu-squash/releases/download/1.2-0f285b8f/', 'file': 'filesystem.squashfs', 'url': 'https://github.com/netbootxyz/ubuntu-squash/releases/download/1.2-0f285b8f/filesystem.squashfs'}}) => {
"ansible_loop_var": "item", 
"changed": false, 
"checksum_dest": "f81cc8c2e941746ec359d93ab4ce6b14f75af225", 
"checksum_src": "f81cc8c2e941746ec359d93ab4ce6b14f75af225", 
"dest": "/var/www/html/live/ubuntu-squash/releases/download/1.2-0f285b8f/filesystem.squashfs", 
"elapsed": 94, 
"gid": 0, 
"group": "root", 
"item": {
  "key": "regolith-current", 
  "value": {
    "dest": "/var/www/html/live/ubuntu-squash/releases/download/1.2-0f285b8f/", 
    "file": "filesystem.squashfs", 
    "url": "https://github.com/netbootxyz/ubuntu-squash/releases/download/1.2-0f285b8f/filesystem.squashfs"
  }
}, 
"md5sum": "285b019b7a2d91c5400b6c9991de2a60", 
"mode": "0644", 
"msg": "OK (2097151999 bytes)", 
"owner": "root", 
"size": 2097151999, 
"src": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624984184.2966168-188394881121369/tmphilspaat", 
"state": "file", 
"status_code": 200, 
"uid": 0, 
"url": "https://github.com/netbootxyz/ubuntu-squash/releases/download/1.2-0f285b8f/filesystem.squashfs"}
```

As you can see the
`"src": "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1624984184.2966168-188394881121369/tmphilspaat"`
and `"elapsed": 94`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the problem was caused by a bug in the `get_url` module. Updating to the latest version of ansible fixed it.

Some info about `get_url` and its parameters:
Your file is downloaded every time, because `dest` is a directory.
From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-dest):

> If `dest` is a directory, the file will always be downloaded (regardless of the `force` option), but replaced only if the contents changed..

You have to include the name of the file into `dest` if you do not want ansible to download the file.
An even better option is to additionally provide the checksum of the file. This will
a) verify the downloaded artifact, so you will always be sure you got what you are looking for and
b) only download the file, if the file at `dest` does not match the provided checksum (e.g. if it changed on the host).
Check out the [documentation of the checksum parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-checksum) for further information.

By the way, your code is not valid `yaml`. This works for me:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  become: true
  vars:
    dl:
      4mlinux:
        dest: /tmp/test/36.1-39ff9a19/
        file: vmlinuz
        url: https://github.com/netbootxyz/asset-mirror/releases/download/36.1-39ff9a19/vmlinuz
      4mlinux-antivirus:
        dest: /tmp/test/37.0-0.103.2-ba9e3ece/
        file: vmlinuz
        url: https://github.com/netbootxyz/asset-mirror/releases/download/37.0-0.103.2-ba9e3ece/vmlinuz
      4mlinux-bakandimg:
        dest: /tmp/test/36.0-262576bf/
        file: vmlinuz
        url: https://github.com/netbootxyz/asset-mirror/releases/download/36.0-262576bf/vmlinuz
  tasks:
    - name: Download File
      get_url:
        url: "{{ item.value.url }}"
        dest: "{{ item.value.dest }}{{ item.value.file }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', dl) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already read that with the full File name at the Documentation.
It should be right in the task "dest="{{ item.value.dest }}{{item.value.file }}"".
I have no checksum for the Files I want to Download.
Even if I had the checksum, i could only calculate it when I download the whole file.
Or am I wrong with this ?

Comment: In that case make sure, that `vmlinuz` doesn't exist and is not a directory. About the checksum: You can download the file to your machine once and calculate the checksum (e.g. `wget https://github.com/...vmlinuz` and `sha256sum vmlinuz`) use that as shown in the example in the documentation.

Comment: The File didnt exist on the first run of the Playbook. It is was downloaded after the run.  But each run downloads the File again. The Problem with the checksum ist, that when I check against it ansible definitive needs to download the File and that is what I'd like to prevent.

Comment: No, it does not. That is the whole point of the checksum. If ansible finds a file that matches that checksum, it will not download it.  You do *not* compute the checksum in the playbook. You compute it once and just add the value to the playbook.

Comment: that is clear to me.When i download the file calculate the Checksum and place it in  my playbook, how does ansible know the checksum of the remote file ?  I have not seen a Header which includes the Checksum.

Comment: You tell ansible "download `file`, checksum is `a`" (in your playbook). Ansible checks if the file exists. If it does *not*, it downloads the file and checks if the checksum matches. If it *does exist*, it checks the checksum of the existing file. If that matches, it will not download the file again. If it does *not* match, it will download the file and replace the existing one.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I upvoted your answer but have not enough reputation to show :( , now it is clear to me that the Checksum check happens local against the local file and not the file on the remote Server as i assumed. It would be great if I can avoid the generation of the checksums, because the download.yaml gets generated from another File on a regular base. For me it would be sufficient if get_url or another command only check the size.

Comment: You can accept my answer, if it answers your question. Click the check-mark next to the answer to do that. I just updated my answer. I tested that code and ansible does not download the files if they exist. So this works for me.

Comment: Ansible Downloads still the whole File, I editet one Example verbose Output in the Question

Comment: Which version of ansible are you using. I tested this again, it works fine for me. Updated my answer with a full playbook.

Comment: I use Version 2.9.6 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I will try it again with your Playbook. But I think the only differnece from mine is, that i read  the vars from a File instead of define them in the Playbook.

Comment: Try upgrading ansible, this might be an old bug.

Comment: Upgrading to ansible [core 2.11.2] fixed it. Would you like to edit your answer ?